# How to show that $\lim_{x\to 1}(x^3-1)/(x-1)=3$?

Tags: limits

How to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}=3?
$$
I tried to solve but couldn't. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try factoring the polynomial in the numerator? or long division to simplify the quotient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x\neq 1$, then (this is a geometric sum)
$$
1+x+x^2=\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}.
$$
I guess you can proceed from here?

**Edit**
Although I think that it is good to know and recognize geometric series, here are two other ways.

1) L'Hospital.
$$
\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{3x^2}{1}=3.
$$

2) Since the polynomial $f(x)=x^3-1$ satisfies $f(1)=0$, we know by the factor theorem that $(x-1)$ is a factor of $f(x)$. Long polynomial division gives
$$
\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}=x^2+x+1.
$$
Then, the limit is easily seen to be $3$.

3) The function $f(x)=x^3$ is differentiable everywhere, with derivative $f'(x)=3x^2$. By the definition of derivative
$$
3=f'(1)=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}.
$$

Choose any way, but I still like the one with geometric series best.

Comment: how did you come to this step? I am not able to solve it even.

Comment: Honestly, I just recognized it. If one does not do that, I suggest to do a polynomial long division.

Comment: It's [arguably] easier to recognize the *difference of cubes* and then to factor.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 We are all different. I saw a geometric sum, you a difference of cubes. I like yours too.

Comment: I would have my limit approach a different x-value, if that's what you mean :)

Comment: Technically the L'Hospital derivation is really the same as the third derivation. That is, by definition the limit is $f'(1)$ where $f(x)=x^3$, and L'Hospital just tells you that the limit is $f'(1)/1$, so it's the same situation.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to tell people struggling with this kind of problem to use L'Hopital.  L'Hopital depends on derivatives, and derivatives depend on finding limits like this one. It's important that they know that this can be done by simple methods that don't require derivatives.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I somehow agree with you, yet I will let it stand there. I think that the first method, (to use polynomial division/geometric sum) is the best point of view on this one.

Comment: @Ian I agree. It is just another point of view on the same situation.

Comment: thanks for the solution and especialy for Lhospital rule...

Answer (score 3):

Hint $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ and $x$ is not exactly $1$.

Comment: thanks now I can solve it...

Comment: Gd i just gave hint so you solve it yourself and learn the way:)

Comment: Or just practice

Comment: I liked the comment "x is not exactly 1". Key point.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $x^3-1$ becomes $0$ when $x=1$ tells you that $x-1$ is a factor of $x^3-1$.  So you have
$$
x^3-1 = (x-1)(\cdots\cdots).
$$
You can find the other factor by long division, then cancel $x-1$ from the numerator and the denominator.  After that it's easy.

Basic fact from algebra.  If you plug a number (e.g. $4$) into a polynomial and get $0$, then $x$ minus that number (e.g. $x-4$) is a factor of that polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = y+1$,
so we want to see what happens as $y \to 0$.

Note:
I almost always want to have
a variable that controls a limit
go to zero
instead of some other value
(like $1$ in this case).

\begin{align}
\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}
&=\frac{(y+1)^3-1}{(y+1)-1}\\
&=\frac{(y^3+3y^2+3y+1)-1}{y}\\
&=\frac{y^3+3y^2+3y}{y}\\
&=y^2+3y+3
\qquad\text{whenever }y \ne 0\\
&\to 3 \qquad\text{as } y \to 0\\
\end{align}

Note that this shows that
$\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}
=(x-1)^2+3(x-1)+3
$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use polynomial long division (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) on this problem
$$(x^3-1):(x-1)=x^2+x+1$$

Then taking the limit is reduced to setting $x=1$ into $x^2+x+1$.